Raspberry Pi 5 running Gentoo Linux is not able to mount partitions at first
I have a Pi 5 with a 64-bit, systemd-based Gentoo Linux on it, and every time it starts it gets held up with four jobs: making a file system check for /dev/mmcblk0p3, my root partition, trying to mount /dev/mmcblk0p1, my boot partition, trying to activate my swap partition /dev/mmcblk0p2 and trying to do something with /dev/ttyAMA10. The section of the boot log where this happens reads:
Jul 29 11:39:07 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev gracefully.
Jul 29 11:39:07 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Finished swap with zram.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p1.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p1.device/start timed out.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mmcblk0p1.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: boot.mount: Job boot.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p1.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Unnecessary job was removed for /dev/ttyAMA10.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p2.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p2.device/start timed out.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mmcblk0p2.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/mmcblk0p2.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swaps.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p2.swap: Job dev-mmcblk0p2.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p2.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p2.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 29 11:40:37 gentoowohnzimmer systemd[1]: systemd-ask-password-console.path: Deactivated successfully.

After this, the Pi enters emergency mode, then, when I press Ctrl+D to continue with the boot, it mounts all of these partitions successfully and boots normally. My fstab reads
/dev/mmcblk0p3      /       f2fs        defaults,noatime        0 1
/dev/mmcblk0p1      /boot       vfat        noatime,nodev,nosuid    1 2
/dev/mmcblk0p2      none        swap        sw      0 0
/dev/cdrom      /mnt/cdrom  auto        noauto,ro   0 0

though I've also tried replacing all options of the relevant partitions with defaults and the problem remains. My cmdline.txt reads
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 rootfstype=f2fs elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait

Though I've also tried using the partition UUID of the root partition, with the same result. The relevant portion of my config.txt reads
cmdline=cmdline.txt
arm_64bit=1
kernel=kernel8.img

I've taken over most of this configuration from my Pi 4, where it worked, and replaced the options specific to the Pi 5. I initially made a mistake, which was that I installed rpi-eeprom with the pi4 USE-flag, but I corrected that by re-emerging rpi-eeprom and updating the eeprom (for the first time). I also formatted the root partition to f2fs, which was supported by default on the Pi 4, and added the kernel=kernel8.img line so the Pi 5 could use f2fs, as suggested here.
Any ideas as to what could cause this problem?

Since nobody seemed to know a solution, I ended up switching my file system to ext4 and using the 16k page kernel. Now booting seems to work normally.
